# Linear application in canonical basis

Tags: linear-algebra, canonical-transformation

I have the function $f:\mathbb C^3 \to \mathbb C^3$, $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (4x_1 + 2x_2, x_1+4x_2+x_3, x_1+x_2+4x_3)^t$. $t$ stands for transposed

How can I determine if it is an linear application and it's matrix in a canonical basis?

Comment: Do you know the definition of linearity? There are two conditions to check: your function should commute with vector addition, and with scalar multiplication. You need to verify both of these properties. As for finding its matrix in the canonical basis, the recipe for doing that should be in any textbook on basic linear algebra. You'll need to compute the values of $f$ on the canonical basis vectors, and form these into a matrix in the right way.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the definition of linearity to check if this holds for the given function.

To find the corresponding matrix using the canonical basis take you should calculate $f(1,0,0), f(0,1,0)$ and $f(0,0,1)$ (that is the images of the canocical basis vectors) which gives you the columns of the matrix. The article on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Matrices) might also be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can think that your function $f:{\Bbb C}^3\longrightarrow{\Bbb C}^3$ can be expressed as
$$x=\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\end{array}\right)
\longmapsto
f(x)=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
4&1&1\\
2&4&1\\
0&1&4
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\end{array}\right),$$
so, by attending the above Hirshy and Keenan Kidwell's recommendation's you can settle your questions.